# Highlight XML code in string literal in pycharm

Tags: xml, pycharm

Pycharm seems to support [language injection according to the help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/using-language-injections.html). This should be able to highlight xml in string literals. But it seems that that [help page was "copy/pasted" from the IDEA IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/using-language-injections.html).

It does not seem to work with pycharm.

Has anyone had success with this?

The XML highlighting in XML files is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
x = '''
<x xmlns:foo="http://test" foo="1">
<foo:y>27</foo:y>
</x>
'''
```

...and it matched the highlighting defined in `Preferences -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> XML`.